# Injective mapping into the Cantor set

Tags: measure-theory

Let $ X \subset [0,1]$ and $f:X \rightarrow C$ be an injective mapping into a Cantor Set $C$. How do I justify whether $f(X)$ is Lebesgue measurable or not?

The Cantor set $C$ has measure $0$ and since the mapping is injective $X = f^{-1}(C)$ has measure $0$.

Comment: Your statement "The cantor set has measure $0$ and since the mapping is injective, $X$ has measure $0$." is incorrect. Note that the Cantor set has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$ and the interval $[0,1]$. Hence, there exists a bijective mapping from $\mathbb{R}$ (or) from $[0,1] \to F$. And clearly the measure of $\mathbb{R}$ and that of $[0,1]$ is not zero.

Comment: Isn't the Lebesgue measure of the Cantor Set $0$?

Answer (score 3):

Every subset of a measure zero set is Lebesgue measurable.

Answer (score 2):

What you mean to say is that $f(X)$ has measure $0$ because the cantor set has measure $0$ and lebesgue measure is complete.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking along this line itself. However I didn't know whether it was right or not!

Comment: @BhavishSuarez Glad I could help!